# How to use SET_DHTML in an asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv, asynchronous

I'm using the DHTML API from with `wz_dragdrop.js` and `wz_jsgraphics.js` ([source](http://www.walterzorn.de/en/dragdrop/demos/drawonimg.htm)) to draw Rectangles on images. I have a local `.csv` file with the coordinates of the rectangle for all the images on my page.

To retrieve the content of my `.csv` file I've tried all kind of `.csv` readers (Papa Parser, d3, FileReader) and saw that they were all asynchronous and that I couldn't recover the content of my file outside of it. I wanted that because when I call the library's main function `SET_DHTML`, which converts images into draggable DHTML items, in a asynchronous function, there's nothing remaining on my page besides the draggable images.

Is there any way to retrieve the data from the `.csv` file and using this function without losing everything on my page?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>TEST</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
    <table cellspacing="12">
      <tr>
        <td>TEST FACE RECOGNITION</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
  </center>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/reischle/instaperimeter/master/wz_dragdrop.js"></script>
   <img name="img1" src="http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/001/330/335/b84.png" alt="HTML5" style="visibility: hidden;" width=300 height=200/>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    var data;
    function getData(callback) { $.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openmundi/world.csv/master/countries(204)_olympics.csv", function(response) { callback(response); }); }   


    getData(function (data) { 
   console.log("The data is: " + data);
   SET_DHTML("img1"); // Erase everything except the draggable image - comment this line and uncomment the same one bellow to see the difference
   });
    console.log(data); // undefined because synchronous
    //SET_DHTML("img1"); // Works fine, keep everything and the draggable image
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: DHTML? Is this 1998? *edit* actually, after reading the link in your first paragraph it would appear so as the logic and concepts presented are *incredibly* outdated. I'd suggest looking for a more up to date library to meet your needs.

Comment: It's also not at all clear what you're asking, or are attempting to do. What do you mean by 'without losing everything on your page'?

Comment: I'm new to js, what recent library would you recommand to draw on image? If you look at my fiddle, you'll see that when the SET_DHTML function is present in the getData function, everything but the new draggable image disapear. But if you comment this line and uncomment the same one bellow, there is the draggable image and the rest of my page.